# pmap not mapping across rows of dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to map a function to multiple inputs contained in
rows of a dataframe using `purrr::pmap`. I've got a `reprex`
below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create dummy data
e <- 0.3
f <- 1:3
g <- 1:3
df <- tidyr::crossing(e = e, f = f, g = g)

# Create a simple function to use
new_ratio <- function(x, y, z){
    return(x/(y + z))
}

# Apply pmap across rows of the dataframe `df` - not working as intended 
purrr::pmap(df, ~ new_ratio(x = e, y = f, z = g))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 0.150 0.075 0.050
```

Created on 2018-07-16 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

As it can be seen I really want to create a simple output
**row by row** to give the ratio `e/(f+g)` in this 
simple example. The function keeps returning the same values
for different inputs. In the first row, I would expect the 
output `0.3/(1 + 1) = 0.15`, in the second row would expect
`0.3/(1 + 2) = 0.1` etc

Could anyone please show how to correct for this? I am not quite
understanding how to apply `pmap` from the documentation

Comment: Why do you want to use `pmap` when `df %>%
  mutate(new = new_ratio(e, f, g))` works ? I am not sure if this is the right example to use `pmap`.

Comment: Thanks. In this simple case your suggestion will work as we are just returning a number which can be placed in a new column through `mutate`. Though if you replace `new_ratio` with a more complicated function that returns a big list (for each output) then pmap is what I want to do. The `df` created here creates every input combination in my actual use case in a clean way. Would be great to map my function across every row (i.e. input combination) and get a separate list back hence the request for `pmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the column names to the argument names and it should work

```
pmap_dbl(setNames(df, c('x', 'y', 'z')), new_ratio)
#[1] 0.150 0.100 0.075 0.100 0.075 0.060 0.075 0.060 0.050
```

Or if we intend to use `~`, the arguments are `..` followed by the number

```
pmap_dbl(df, ~ new_ratio(x = ..1, y= ..2, z = ..3))
#[1] 0.150 0.100 0.075 0.100 0.075 0.060 0.075 0.060 0.050
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I was close but the way the inputs are passed into `pmap` is not that obvious. Thanks for clarifying. I feel option 1 is the cleanest way i.e. aligning names in the correct order.